# How to add contextual gadget on personal gmail

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Can we use contextual gadget on my personal gmail OR do I have to purchase and app domain for this?

My mainfeast.json is

```
     {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "unsendMe-AddContact",
  "version": "0.0.0.2",
  "description": "Grab the contact of the mail sender and save .",
   "icons": {
    "128": "ICON_PLACE3 (2) (Custom) (2).png",
    "16": "ICON_PLACE3 (2) (Custom).png"
  },
 "container": ["app"],
  "api_console_project_id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail Contextual Gadgets are not available on your personal email.  You will need to purchase an enterprise account.

Your manifest doesn't look right - you should check out the link below for the full details:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#hello_world_example_manifest

Comment: is there any google documentation for this restriction of personal gmail ..would u provide a link.

Comment: I don't know where that is documented but if you search Google you should find something.  Adding from the marketplace requires a domain so with personal Gmail you don't have that for example.  You can produce the equivalent of a contextual gadget by manipulating the DOM using a Chrome extension.  Simply build a Chrome Extension and get it to manipulate the DOM of Gmail - add your UI/logic and you can have the same functionality as a gadget.  We have done this and there are many examples out there.